# Developing an in-game Java overlay

Tags: java, overlay, fullscreen

Would it be possible to develop and in-game overlay that could run a application as a child process and thus gain the ability to remain overlayed in fullscreen mode? By default fullscreened applications (Games and not exactly Youtube videos) tell the OS to stop rendering other processes because it is fullscreen to save on resources. However would making it a childprocess workaround that, and if so could it a trigger and Anti-Cheat?

Comment: (1) this is awfully vague. (2) It sounds more like something in C++ would work better. Java might be too limiting in what it can do for clients when it comes to an idea like this.

Comment: By default fullscreen applications tell the OS to "halt" the drawing of other applications and only focus on the current fullscreen application, but if I still wanted to draw an application on top of that fullscreen application would making the fullscreen app a childprocess of the other one work around that?

Comment: Also my main fear of C++ / C# would require something like D3D injection/hooking which could potentially trigger some anti-cheat and would not by cross-os compatable